# How to handle logging in Android JUnit tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

I would like to log information in model classes - not necessarily for unit testing purposes but for real life scenarios where I am trying to debug.

However, if I try to use `android.util.Log` methods I get the following errors when running JUnit tests:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method d in android.util.Log not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

I understand *why* this occurs, I should not be using Android framework code in model classes that are designed to be framework independent!  I'm not really arguing against the error, but rather I am trying to find a way to work around this.

I have one idea, does this make sense?

Create a `CustomLog` class along these lines:

```
public class CustomLog {
    private static ILogger mLogger;

    public static void setLogger(ILogger logger) {
        mLogger = logger;
    }

    public static void e(String tag, String message) {
        mLogger.e(tag, message);
    }
}
```

Where `ILogger` is an interface with the required methods to perform the log functionality (e, d, etc. methods...)

I could create an `ILoggerImpl` that uses the `android.util.Log` methods, and a `MockLogger` class that simply prints out to `System.out.println` and/or does nothing (or anything else!).

I think that'd perfectly fit my needs (I would be required to setup my `CustomLog` class very early on in the lifecycle, but that's not a huge deal).

However, if I ever needed to add third party libraries/outside code to my model classes, this would likely break again in the same manner if the new libraries/code use `android.util.Log` methods.

So, is there a "catch all" type behavior I could use?  What do you think?

Comment: You can use `System.out.println()` which is maybe not perfect, but shows up in the test outputs.

Comment: Definitely.  I explained that here: "I could create an `ILoggerImpl` that uses the `android.util.Log` methods, and a `MockLogger` class that simply prints out to `System.out.println` and/or does nothing (or anything else!)." - my question pertains to _how_ to get this working nicely.  `System.out.println` for unit testing but `android.util.Log` for debug/release non unit testing!

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I think you found the best you can really do then.

Comment: _I_ think so too ;) - but I'd like to get more thoughts if possible! Thank you for your feedback though!

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving the "Not mocked" exception you cited is to [use PowerMockito to mock the `Log`ging methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39172060/1298153). Instead of calling `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Log.class);` as explained in the linked answer, you can take inspiration from [this](https://blog.jayway.com/2013/03/05/beyond-mocking-with-powermock/), and use PowerMockito to `replace()` `Android.util`'s `Log.v`, `Log.d`, `Log.i` & `Log.e` with methods that will run `System.out.println` instead. This allows you to see the logged messages in Android Studio's Run window.

```
String[] logMethods = {"v", "d", "i", "e"};
InvocationHandler systemOutPrintln = new InvocationHandler() {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            String arg = args[i].toString();
            messageBuilder.append(arg);
            // add separators, ASCII art, ...
        }
        System.out.println(messageBuilder);
        return messageBuilder.toString().length();
    }
};

for (String logMethod : logMethods) {
    replace(method(Log.class, logMethod, String.class, String.class)).with(systemOutPrintln);
    replace(method(Log.class, logMethod, String.class, String.class, Throwable.class)).with(systemOutPrintln);
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if the above is the most idiomatic implementation.

Comment: Personally I think this violates the principle that model code should not have Android dependencies in it, at all, but sure this _would_ work I think!