# java.lang.RuntimeException: Method i in android.util.Log not mocked

Tags: android

I am working in android studio.
I'm training to understand how to do unit testing. 
when I run my test i have this error:
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Method i in android.util.Log not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.**

thank in advance.

```
    package com.bignerdranch.android.beatbox;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

public class SoundViewModelTest {
    private BeatBox mBeatBox;
    private Sound mSound;
    private SoundViewModel mSubject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mBeatBox = mock(BeatBox.class);
        mSound = new Sound("assetPath");
        mSubject = new SoundViewModel(mBeatBox);
        mSubject.setSound(mSound);
    }

    @Test
    public void exposesSoundNameAsTitle() {
        assertThat(mSubject.getTitle(), is(mSound.getName()));
    }


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock method e in Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787449/how-to-mock-method-e-in-log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use PowerMock for this. 
Before you declare your test class you have to put the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Log.class})
```

And then, inside the @Before method:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Log.class);
```