# how to mock android.util.Log

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

I.m using a mockk library in kotlin, and in tests, I have the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getStackTraceString in android.util.Log not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

I can't find a solution for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to add

```
testOptions { 
  unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

in `android` section in your `build.gradle` file. It will mock some call to Android platform. Please note that it just return default values.

In the new gradle plugin this property was renamed to `isReturnDefaultValues`.

Comment: please note that as [The comment in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42653151/9735961) pointed out, this is **NOT** mocking some call to Android platform, but just return default values, which might cause problems as "the null/zero return values can introduce regressions in your tests".

Comment: The unitTests variable name has changed to `isReturnDefaultValues`: https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/UnitTestOptions#isreturndefaultvalues