# Cannot see log from unit test in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, logging, mockk

I'm working on an Android app written in Kotlin. I would like to use Log.* to see the output of some very simple logic in a unit test, rendered as string. I'm using [mockk](https://mockk.io/) as suggestested in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55251961).

I don't get any errors, the test works fine; however, not even a single line is printed in the Logcat of Android Studio. I checked filters and current device with no avail.

Here is my simplified code:

```
// UnitTest.kt
class MyUnitTest {
  @Before
  fun setup() {
    mockkStatic(Log::class)
    every { Log.d(any(), any()) } returns 0
  }

  @Test
  fun do_test() {
    // ... some logic
    Log.d("TEST_TAG", "Test string")
  }
}
```

I also tried to:

- put the Log in a function marked as `@JvmStatic` into a companion object
- adding the following to app level `build.gradle` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57958441/3861701) (though unrecommended)

```
testOptions {
  unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

- get rid of everything and use a kotlin implementation of the [main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46793567). Something like this:

```
// app/src/test/android/util/MyLog.kt
package android.util

class MyLog {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun d(tag: String, msg: String): Int {
      println("DEBUG: $tag: $msg")
      return 0
    }
}
```

Unfortunately none of these worked (with any of the Log levels).

I don't have great experience in writing tests, am I missing something?

**Edit (about solution):**

I was targeting Logcat, which is wrong, because unit tests run on a local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `println()` for logging in unit tests.

*Logcat* shows messages coming from a device. As unit tests are running on your local machine, it is physically impossible to see messages. `println()` prints messages to the test "console".

Comment: This is what I do when using `MyLog.d()` instead of `Log.d` but I can't still see anything in my Logcat :(

Comment: Logcat shows messages coming from a device. As unit tests are running on your local machine, it is physically impossible to see messages. `println()` prints messages to the test "console"

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! I was sure I was missing some simple technical detail